# Deriving Serde's Serialize or Deserialize forces generic type to be serialisable although it does not need to be

Tags: rust, serde

My type `A`, which can contain anything that implements `trait Trait`, is serialisable, although the type implementing the trait `Trait` might not be. In my case, it cannot be - it's a private asymmetric key:

```
extern crate serde;
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;

use serde::de::DeserializeOwned;
use serde::Serialize;

trait Trait {
    type SerialisableType: Clone + Serialize + DeserializeOwned;

    fn inner(&self) -> &Self::SerialisableType;
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
enum A<T: Trait> {
    Variant0(B<T>), // *** NOTE: Compiles if this is commented ***
    Variant1(T::SerialisableType),
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct B<T: Trait> {
    inner: T::SerialisableType,
}

// ==============================================

struct NonSerialisable {
    serialisable: Serialisable,
}

impl Trait for NonSerialisable {
    type SerialisableType = Serialisable;

    fn inner(&self) -> &Self::SerialisableType {
        &self.serialisable
    }
}

#[derive(Clone, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Serialisable(Vec<u8>);

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
enum E {
    Variant0(A<NonSerialisable>),
    Variant1(B<NonSerialisable>),
}

fn main() {}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=7f73e8eb4689533241b9a8f695d93a0e&version=stable&mode=debug)

This errors out with:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `NonSerialisable: serde::Serialize` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:43:10
   |
43 | #[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
   |          ^^^^^^^^^ the trait `serde::Serialize` is not implemented for `NonSerialisable`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `serde::Serialize` for `A<NonSerialisable>`
   = note: required by `serde::Serializer::serialize_newtype_variant`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `NonSerialisable: serde::Deserialize<'_>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:43:21
   |
43 | #[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `serde::Deserialize<'_>` is not implemented for `NonSerialisable`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `serde::Deserialize<'_>` for `A<NonSerialisable>`
   = note: required by `serde::de::VariantAccess::newtype_variant`
```

If I comment out `A::Variant0`, as mentioned in the inline comment in the code, then it compiles fine. This makes me think that the compiler is unable to deduce that `B<T>` is serialisable, but then it actually is able to deduce that because it can figure out `E` is serialisable which would require `B` to be serialisable as well.

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

During macro expansion the compiler has not yet determined which `B` is being referred to inside `Variant0` or how that `B` may use its type parameters. As such, macro expansion infers trait bounds that would work for the most common cases of what `B` might be, like if `B` were `Box` or `Vec`. In those cases serializing `B<T>` would require `T: Serialize` and deserializing `B<T>` would require `T: Deserialize<'de>`.

You can provide [handwritten generic type bounds](https://serde.rs/attr-bound.html) to replace the inferred bounds.

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(bound = "")]
enum A<T: Trait> {
    Variant0(B<T>),
    Variant1(T::SerialisableType),
}
```

Comment: that worked - i actually had `#[serde(bound(deserialize = ""))]` already in actual implementation due to prior errors. Then the crate with the trait compiled and only when I'm now using it in another crate is that giving an error. Looks pretty strange as I come to know to modify a crate only when it's later used by another one. Anyway I made the `bound = ""` (as you suggested) instead of just deserialize bound and now it works. Thanks !